# No controller or VM in AngularJS view?

Tags: angularjs

How is this working?  Does AngularJS require any mention of the scripts for it to work?

I've always used the "controller as" syntax in AngularJS.  However, I just purchased a template and there is NO MENTION of the controller in the HTML.  There's no `LoginCtrl as vm` or any other mention of any back-end scripting.

```
$stateProvider.state('realLogin', {
    url: '/real-login',

    views: {
        root: {
            templateUrl: "app/auth/login/login.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
        }
    },
    data: {
        title: 'Login',
        rootId: 'extra-page'
    }

})
```

And the HTML is...

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center animated fadeInDown">
            <div>
                <h1 class="logo-name">My Orange</h1>
            </div>
            <h3>Welcome to My Orange</h3>

            <p>Perfectly designed and precisely prepared admin theme with over 50 pages with extra new web app views.
            </p>

            <p>Login in. To see it in action.</p>

            <form class="m-t" role="form" action="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block m-b">Login</button>

                <a ui-sref="account.forgot">
                    <small>Forgot password?</small>
                </a>

                <p class="text-muted text-center">
                    <small>Do not have an account?</small>
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" ui-sref="account.register">Create an account</a>

                <br/>

                <google-signin></google-signin>

                <facebook-signin></facebook-signin>

                <br/>
            </form>
            <p class="m-t">
                <small>My Orange app framework base on Bootstrap 3 © 2014</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you are mention in state config. `controller: 'LoginCtrl as vm'`

Comment: Figured.  Still feels very odd.  Nesting views must get disgusting.

Comment: The definition of the controller is handled by the state service, in the configuration you can add `controllerAs:'vm'`, or you can delete the declaration in the state and put in the template html corresponding to the state.

Comment: The **vm** approach is great for using inside controllers, but is considered bad practice on templates, just as you mentioned, because if your project scales, you can easily lose track of what controller is doing what in your code. I would recommend the approach of 'LoginController as loginCtrl', 'HomeController as homeCtrl'. The moment you got your eyes on the code, you know exactly where to find that method/variable.